# Python url title problem

Tags: python

```
import lxml.html, sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    url2 = arg
    t = lxml.html.parse(url2)
if arg == "":
    url = raw_input("Website URL: ")
    t = lxml.html.parse(url)
print t.find(".//title").text
```

Problem is with [if arg == "":]
I want to have something like "if there is no arg, then:", but I don't know how.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print 'no arg'
```

**Edit**: There is one more issue in your code:

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    ...
```

Should be:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    ...
```

since the first argument is the python file name itself